# CART coverall accuracy vs. RF & SVM

Tags: random-forest, cart, validation

I am performing a supervised classification with RF, SVM, and CART algorithms.
I have over 2000 training points in an area of 9,995 km².

For CART, I have obtained a 'Validation overall accuracy = 1' when I set minLeafPopulation as default value 1.
(If I set minLeafPopulation  = 2, it decreases the accuracy to 0.94)

I read that such a high accuracy is not possible and it might be due to errors in training data, so I checked the 'Training overall accuracy'' as well and it is 0.9994.

For the same dataset, the 'validation overall accuracy 'of RF and SVM are 0.81 and 0.88, respectively.

At first, I was sure that this result is wrong but since the other two algorithms do not result in such high accuracy, I am not sure if the CART accuracy is wrong. Is it really possible??

Comment: Are you computing the OA using an independent validation dataset never seen during training? It is strange to obtain OA=1. The following could be happening?: you have an overtrained CART and repeated samples in train and validation datasets. Note that if two points intersect with the same pixel the samples will be the same.

Comment: @sermomon thank you. Yes, I used the randomColumn() to split my data 80% for training and 20% to validation.  I have some sample data close to each other perhaps but I do not think on the same pixel. Anyway, if the training data is bad, why RF and SVM have more reasonable results?

Comment: If you have a bad training data this make sense because RF and SVM are more robust to overtraining than CARTs. However, I think it is a difficult problem to understand without exploring the data in depth. I would consider it closed.

Comment: You might need to sample your validation set better. Your data is correlated over space. You'll underestimate the training error if you pick the validation set at random. See  https://towardsdatascience.com/spatial-cross-validation-using-scikit-learn-74cb8ffe0ab9